# Automated JBoss AS7 configuration whilst the server is down

Tags: xml, configuration, jboss7.x

We have a requirement that whilst we deploy and update our JBoss applications, JBoss should be down and we only bring it up when the necessary down stream systems are available.
This means that any configuration (i.e. standalone.xml updates) have to be done offline as we can't use CLI with the server down.

Each environment we host will have different configuration settings and different applications and as such we can't simply replicate the standalone.xml for each installation. We also don't want to manualy update the .xml in a text editor as we need to automate the rollout and want to avoid mistakes.

For our other (non JBoss) applications our solution is for dev to produce a configuration template and then the installation teams (using automated tools) take that template, add in the environment specific values, and place the resultant file in the target location.

The problem we have with JBoss is that all the JBoss applications that are in the environment have their conifg in the same single file (standalone.xml). As such we can't associate a standalone.xml template with any single application. SO the problem is if we're updating 'JBoss App A' but not 'JBoss App B' or 'JBoss App C' how do we update the standalone.xml configuration for 'Jboss App A' without losing the config for apps B & C?

It would be OK if JBoss was up as we could have a config tool (i.e. CLI script) that runs off an application specific config file. The config file would be managed as per the above non JBoss apps and the CLI script, using the config file, would ba able to update standalone.xml without upsetting the other apps. So I guess what we're after is a tool that can do what CLI can do, but without JBoss being up. Anybody know of such a thing?

Apologies for the length of the query! Hope someone has come across a tool that can do this. The dev team are scratching their heads at the moment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start your process in admin-mode - i.e. the server starts up it's management capabilities but does not start the subsystems, this way you can then execute CLI scripts to update the configuration.

./standalone.sh --admin-only

Comment: Thanks very much Darran L - will touch base with my dev guys on your solution. Didn't know there was that capability. We're also looking at tools like Augeas